# Get product store URLs for products using REST API in Magento 2

Tags: rest, magento, magento2

I am trying to fetch products information using REST API

`GET    /V1/products`

but, this does not give product store urls for the products.

How can I get the product urls mapped to product sku or id using REST APIs in magento2?

Answer (score 0):

Look in the `custom_attributes` array where `item`.`attribute_code`=`url_key`

For example, if I make a REST API call to `http://localhost/~harrym/Magento/rest/V1/products/TestTEST`. I get this payload back as xml, for this product (`testabc.html`) at `http://localhost/~harrym/Magento/testabc.html`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response>
  <id>164</id>
  <sku>TestTEST</sku>
  ...
  <custom_attributes>
    <item>
      <attribute_code>meta_title</attribute_code>
      <value>Test</value>
    </item>
    ...
    <item>
      <attribute_code>url_key</attribute_code>
      <value>testabc</value>
    </item>
  </custom_attributes>
</response>
```